# Ctrl+Shift+E inserts special characters into file instead of showing Explorer Pane in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I prefer having the "Activity Bar" hidden and use the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> to reach the individual panes.

When I am in the Search pane (revealed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) with focus on the editor, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> with the intention of reaching the Explorer pane; instead of exposing the Explorer pane, code inserts the character `e` with a black underline.

Now, I suppose this is some feature to insert special characters into editors but, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as a shortcut for this seems little too conspicuous don't you think? Especially when it is already being used for something else?

I'm not sure when this behavior was changed but I remember that it used to work earlier. Is there a way by which I can disable this special character insertion feature and restore order?

Comment: maybe this is a feature of windows for entering unicode sequences ? That's why you have the black underline, it waits for another input to group this character with

Comment: solution to solve snap issue - https://askubuntu.com/a/1269239/229740

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, it took some time to narrow down this issue. It appears, GTK3 reserves the key combination Ctrl+Shift+E to insert Emoji.

Good news is, this feature has been [removed in GTK version 3.24](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/commit/8be12a2427927cf914c6223c6a2e1267352c40da). You can update your GTK version to fix this issue.

Comment: Even if you have GTK 3.24+, VSCode installed from Snap Store appears to be stuck with an older GTK version. Installing VSCode the normal way (`sudo apt install code`) solved the problem for me.

Comment: HolyBlackCats comment is still true in 2020. [Here's a way](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-20-04/#installing-visual-studio-code-with-apt) to install VS Code using `apt`. The version from the Snap Store can be removed with `snap remove code`.

Comment: If you want to keep using the snap version; [here's a way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125726/how-to-disable-ctrl-shift-e-keybinding-from-showing-eeeee-and-loading-emoji-opti/1269239#1269239)

Comment: This is broken on Ubuntu 22.04 with gtk version 2.34 so this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 15):

This is a very good workaround.

Run `ibus-setup` in the terminal. A GUI dialog will open.

Go to the 'Emoji' tab --> Emoji annotation ellipsis(...) buttton --> Delete 'Ctrl + Shift + E' entry --> OK.

That's it. Works for me on Ubuntu 20.04. You can still access emojis using `Ctrl + .`(period).

Comment: works like a charm in Fedora 36 :D

Comment: I had to run `sudo ibus-setup` to get the GUI dialog box.

Answer (score 11):

As [HolyBlackCats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) and [Pida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487047/pida) stated in comments, the best way is to install Visual Studio Code by ["sudo apt install"](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-20-04/#installing-visual-studio-code-with-apt) on your Ubuntu, as the problem still exists (even after 2 years).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
sudo apt install code
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and still have the same problem in 2021 but this solution works. Just abandon the snap installation. Then search for `showActiveFileInExplorer` in your keyboard shortcuts if that's what you want this keybinding for.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of snap installation, go with the apt one.
First of all remove your vscode snap package

```
sudo snap remove code
```

And then, follow the instructions on the official page

```
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux
```

Or if youre lazy like me, paste this lines into your terminal

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
sudo apt install code
```

Comment: This problem still exist when installed from official deb package.

Comment: Well, it worked here on Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling vscode is a huge pain in the ass. The way I found less annoying was to switch shortcuts. Instead of Ctrl + shift + e, I now use Ctrl + e, the previous shortcut ( Ctrl + e ) can still be accessed through Ctrl + shift + p.

1. Go to your Shortcuts ( Ctrl + K, Ctrl + S )
2. Type "ctrl + shift + e"
3. On "View: Show explorer" double click on keybinding, and press the new keybinding ( in my case was Ctrl + E )
4. Then type "ctrl + e" on the search bar again
5. Remove the other binds with Ctrl + E, except the "View: Show explorer" one

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with the `snap` version of VS Code. Using the `apt` version instead solves the issue.

```
sudo snap remove code
sudo apt install code
```

Just summarizing the answers so far because currently the fix is in a comment from HolyBlackCat rather than in an answer.